# Unable to get details from my laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and i'm trying to create a simple application. But its showing error when i try to get details from the table. 
Here is my code.

This is my controller

```
class TestController extends BaseController
{
public $restful=true;

public function get_index()
{       return View::make('test.index')
            ->with("name", "Sam")
            ->with("test", TestModel::all())
            ;
 }}
```

Model

```
<?php

 class TestModel extends Eloquent
 {
 public static $table="User_details";
  }
 ?>
```

View

```
<html>
<head>        
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hai hello</h1>
    <h3>My name is {{$name}}</h3>
</body>
 </html>
```

But i'm getting the error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Guys please tell me whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Do you see any details of the error in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` ? You can also try changing `debug` to `true` in `app/config/app.php` and then refresh your page in order to see what error is actually being encountered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enable error reporting as suggested to know what's wrong.

By looking at your code, I see you got the wrong visibility (and state) of the $table property. It should be:

```
protected $table = 'User_details';
```

When you extend a class, a property in a child class must inherit the same visibility, and sure not made static when it's not.

Comment: And i enabled error reporting in laravel by debug=>true. But its only displaying error like i said. How can i view detailed error report?